# How to parse JSON using shell command

Tags: json, shell, jenkins

Im pretty new when it comes to shell and I have been able to do something simple as creating a file to my server when I call for a function using Jenkins.

For now I have a command that looks like:

```
"echo '$store;$url;$id' > /home/flags/start_$id.flag"
```

which will create a file with the information for store;url;id and example would be:

```
google;https://www.google.se/;136
```

However I do wonder how I can instead of using ; to split and then converting it to a JSON to instead send the shell command straight to a JSON file so I can read the file as JSON. Is that possible?

Comment: There are shell commands such as [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) that can be used to parse JSON documents.

Comment: Why not just `echo` valid json.  eg `echo "{\"store\": \"$store\" ..."`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I did not know I could do that. I will try that right away

Comment: That was the solution @WilliamPursell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Jenkins will impact what you want to do, but you can typically write valid json in several ways (this is certainly not an exhaustive list, but represents some common ways to do this):

```
echo "{\"store\": \"$store\", \"url\": \"$url\", \"id\":\"$id\"}"
echo '{"store": "'"$store"'", "url": "'"$url"'", "id":"'"$id"'"}'
cat << EOF
{"store": "$store", "url": "$url", "id": "$id"}
EOF
```

The only real difference in the above is how things are quoted.

Comment: I used the first suggestion which was in the comments and it works exactly how I wished to do it :) Thank you very much!